# JSON JavaScriptSerializer maxJsonLength exception (but very small payload)

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an intermittent issue in *MVC5* with the *JSON* parser throwing a `System.InvalidOperationException`:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Straight forward enough, but when I look at the request details, I have no idea why this would happen as the payload is very small:

(not sure how to scrape a raw request from chrome debugger, so):
[image]

The response is straightforward enough:
[image]

Any ideas on something a little less normal that might be causing this?

Comment: Circular reference?

Comment: @AluanHaddad - maybe, not sure how though.  I have just narrowed it down to it only happening with certain search fields filled out for post submission though, so that's a lead.

Comment: You should be using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the size of the JSON request, but rather in the size of the JSON response.

```
return Json(model);
```

This the model was too large, and that's where the exception was coming from (why this wasn't raising in debug instance or logging the exception I'll have to look into...)

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer. Out of curiosity how did you fix it though?

Comment: @garfbradaz Turned out we had a filter criteria that was missed so all results were showing (320k+).  Fix: 1) write a test to ensure filter criteria.  2) implement a maxResults config, 3) write a test to ensure maxResults implementation, 3) provide UI notice that search must be refined, some results omitted.  (can accept answer after 2 days).